# Getting Unhandled exception while giving IPv6 address to Dns.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, dns

While executing below command when I provide IPV4 or machine name it resolve properly but when I provide IPV6 I am getting unhandled exception given below.

How do I resolve IPV6 to host name with using below command.

```
string host = Dns.GetHostEntry(VMName_TestBox.Text).HostName;
```

ERROR:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The requested name is valid, but no data of
>   the requested type was found

Comment: what is the in put argument?

Comment: ipv6 or ipv4 or machine name in string

Comment: are you targeting .NET framework 4.0?

Comment: are you getting the exception just when passing machine name as argument?

Comment: i am getting exception only when i am passing ipv6 address. for ipv4 and machine name no exception

Comment: Does your DNS server support IPv6? Is IPv6 installed on your machine? What does `nslookup <ipv6address>` show you on the command line?

Comment: yes when i ran nslookup with ipv6 address it is giving me correct output given below.

Server: abc.com
Address: 10.10.10.10

Comment: No, that's your DNS server (and it has an IPv4 address). Show the entire command and output in your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419803/how-to-copy-the-contents-in-cmd-prompt-to-notepad how to grab the output of a command prompt.

Comment: C:\Users\tt>nslookup 2077:9876:89:ujh5:11e0:e1ab:hy65:b0ef
Server:  xyz-re-te-65.abc.com
Address:  10.120.10.141

Comment: No. That is your DNS server. There's more output below that.

Comment: (root)
        primary name server = abc.net
        responsible mail addr = abc.com
        serial  = 2087654895
        refresh = 7200 (2 hours)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 2419200 (28 days)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)
*** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for 2077:9876:89:ujh5:11e0:e1ab:hy65:b0ef

Comment: _"No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for <ipv6address>"_ - your DNS server has no record for that IP, and that's exactly what the exception is telling you.

Comment: so now i need to stick with ipv4 or machine name. for ipv6 we need to throw error message.